# Testing form input text value

Tags: wicket

I am testing the following form in my html :

```
   <form wicket:id="form">
          <input type="text" wicket:id="input"/>
           <input type="submit"/>           
   </form>
```

The default value is null and in my test I tried to change it to something and check if I have really changed the field as following:

```
    formTester.setValue(formTester.getForm().get("input"), "randomText");
     Assert.assertEquals("randomText",  formTester.getTextComponentValue("input"));
```

However the test is not successful because the field expected <[randomText]> but was: [].Any ideas why the setting doesn't work?

Comment: For more info check this [link](https://ci.apache.org/projects/wicket/guide/6.x/guide/testing.html)

Answer (score 2):

You need to call `FormTester#submit()` after setting the values of the FormComponents.